# Why does SoundEffect.FromStream() throw InvalidOperationException when reading "valid" WAV files?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to load sound effects into my game (C#/XNA 4.0, Visual Studio 2013 on Win8.1). The game is a "clone" of an existing MMORPG client and should be compatible with the existing directory structure - meaning all the sound effects are stored in a directory named 'sfx' in the game's working directory.

I came across `SoundEffect.FromStream` when attempting to accomplish this. It works great for most of the files I have, but some files throw an InvalidOperationException. The stack trace reveals the error to be located in the internal Wav file constructor within the XNA DLL.

I'm well aware of the [restrictions on wav files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the `SoundEffect.FromStream` method: 8 or 16 bit, mono or stereo, PCM, with sample rate between 8kHz and 48kHz. The problem I am having is that to the best of my knowledge, the specific Wav files that are failing to load meet all of these requirements.

Here is how I am loading the wav files:

```
//SoundInfo is a wrapper around SoundEffect
//  implementation details are not relevant to my question
private readonly List<SoundInfo> m_guitarSounds;
private readonly List<SoundInfo> m_harpSounds;
private readonly List<SoundInfo> m_sounds;

//... additional initialization

foreach (string sfx in soundFiles)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sfx, FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        int samples = getSamplesPerSecond(sfx);

        SoundEffect nextEffect;
        try
        {
            nextEffect = SoundEffect.FromStream(fs);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            //I got this idea from another StackOverflow answer
            nextEffect = new SoundEffect(File.ReadAllBytes(sfx), samples,
                                          AudioChannels.Mono);
        }

        if (sfx.ToLower().Contains("gui"))
            m_guitarSounds.Add(new SoundInfo(nextEffect));
        else if (sfx.ToLower().Contains("har"))
            m_harpSounds.Add(new SoundInfo(nextEffect));
        else
            m_sounds.Add(new SoundInfo(nextEffect));
    }
}
```

On a failure, the effect is constructed from the byte array of data read from the file and forced to Mono. This seems to work for all my errors that arise due to `InvalidOperationException`. The sound is usually quite distorted in these cases.

Below is the code for `getSamplesPerSecond` (referenced in above code):

```
private int getSamplesPerSecond(string filename)
{
    //this method was in place for debugging purposes but is used to get
    //  the samplesPerSec for the audio files that can't be
    //  loaded using FromStream
    byte[] wav = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

    // Get past all the other sub chunks to get to the data subchunk:
    int pos = 12;   // First Subchunk ID from 12 to 16

    //get fmt chunk
    while (!((char)wav[pos] == 'f' && (char)wav[pos + 1] == 'm' && 
            (char)wav[pos + 2] == 't' && (char)wav[pos + 3] == ' '))
    {
        pos += 4;
        int chunkSize = wav[pos] + wav[pos + 1] * 256 + 
                        wav[pos + 2] * 65536 + wav[pos + 3] * 16777216;
        pos += 4 + chunkSize;
    }
    pos += 8;

    int format = wav[pos] + wav[pos + 1]*256;
    pos += 2;
    int channels = wav[pos] + wav[pos + 1]*256;
    pos += 2;
    int samplesPerSec = wav[pos] + wav[pos + 1]*256 + wav[pos + 2]*65536
                        + wav[pos + 3]*16777216;
    pos += 4;
    int avgBytesPerSec = wav[pos] + wav[pos + 1]*256 + wav[pos + 2]*65536
                        + wav[pos + 3] * 16777216;
    pos += 4;
    int blockAlign = wav[pos] + wav[pos + 1]*256;
    pos += 2;

    int bitsPerSample = 0;
    if (format == 1)
    {
        bitsPerSample = wav[pos] + wav[pos + 1]*256;
        //pos += 2; //necessary if we want to look at other chunks
    }

    return samplesPerSec;
}
```

With some debug logging statements thrown in, I got these file contents. This is the only section with failures, and there are only the 9 failures in total (scroll to the right!):

```
sfx\sfx001.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16  
sfx\sfx002.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16    [ FAILED ]
sfx\sfx003.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16    [ FAILED ]
sfx\sfx004.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=22050, BlockAlign=1, BitsPerSample=8  
sfx\sfx005.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16    [ FAILED ]
sfx\sfx006.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16    [ FAILED ]
sfx\sfx007.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16  
sfx\sfx008.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=22050, BlockAlign=1, BitsPerSample=8  
sfx\sfx009.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16  
sfx\sfx010.wav: Format=1, Channels=2, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=88200, BlockAlign=4, BitsPerSample=16    [ FAILED ]
sfx\sfx011.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16  
sfx\sfx012.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16    [ FAILED ]
sfx\sfx013.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16  
sfx\sfx014.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=22050, BlockAlign=1, BitsPerSample=8  
sfx\sfx015.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16  
sfx\sfx016.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16    [ FAILED ]
sfx\sfx017.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16    [ FAILED ]
sfx\sfx018.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16    [ FAILED ]
sfx\sfx019.wav: Format=1, Channels=1, SamplesPerSec=22050, AvgBytesPerSec=44100, BlockAlign=2, BitsPerSample=16
```

The values printed to the above log are printed directly from the getSamplesPerSecond method after reading the WAV file header ('fmt ' chunk). I used http://www.neurophys.wisc.edu/auditory/riff-format.txt as a reference for determining the meaning of the data in the WAV file.

According to my log, each of the files is PCM, 8- or 16-bit, 22050Hz sample rate, and either Mono or Stereo (based on channel count). All the files open perfectly fine in the original game client and work in Audacity as well as Windows Media Player, so I can rule out a problem with the files themselves.

What am I missing here? And if it IS an incompatibility with my source audio files, is there another way I can load them and play them that will work, without using the Content Pipeline?

Comment: Framework code is generally very picky about malformed files, programs that handle those files on a regular basis less so. I suggest you do a side-by-side analysis of a "good" and "bad" file to find out what's different, from that you should be able to narrow down what's causing `SoundEffect.FromStream()` to die.

Comment: @IanKemp That was my goal with the file logging. My first thought was that the sample rate was off. From what I can tell the good and bad files both have the same header, byte for byte. I haven't yet compared the `data` chunks, would the data itself make a difference?

Comment: Certainly could. Maybe there's an optional section of the WAV spec that those files use but `SoundEffect.FromStream()` doesn't understand. Maybe `SoundEffect.FromStream()` has a bug. Maybe other audio players ignore the data that causes `SoundEffect.FromStream()` to crash. The only way you will know is by eliminating the possibilities.

Comment: What exactly was the message with `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: I notice in your `getSamplesPerSecond()` you don't look for the RIFF header but instead leap straight into looking for `fmt ` chunk.  When dealing with RIFF files the **first** thing you should be doing is looking for the first chunk FOURCC `RIFF`.  You should be looking for the `fileType` of `WAVE` within that chunk prior to processing the `fmt` chunk.

Comment: @IanKemp _"Maybe there's an optional section of the WAV spec that those files use but SoundEffect.FromStream() doesn't understand"_ - agreed.  WAV files a RIFF so it is entirely possible that there is a proprietary chunk in the _"'clone' of an existing MMORPG client...existing directory structure"_ [OP]

Comment: _"The game is a 'clone' of an existing MMORPG client and should be compatible with the existing directory structure"_ - so are you saying you are using assets from another game? Is it a commercial game?  Pretty sure there are legality issues in doing so.

Comment: @MickyDuncan The message with `InvalidOperationException` is 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.' I've confirmed that there is a RIFF, Length, and WAVE as the first 12 bytes in each file. I discovered some additional info after the `data` chunk, but it seems to be the same between working and broken files. I'm currently investigating a mismatch between the length after RIFF and the size of the file, I think that might be the problem.

Comment: Highly recommend you use the _mmio_ I/O services to query RIFF data rather than probe raw byte streams.  _[Multimedia file I/O services include two functions you can use to navigate among chunks in a RIFF file: mmioAscend and mmioDescend. You can use these functions as high-level seek functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798636%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)_.    Example: [Performing File I/O on RIFF Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743664(v=vs.85).aspx).  It's c++ but you can p-inoke the appropriate functions

Comment: The files that fail to load, do they play in at least **two other applications**?  e.g. Windows Media Player?

Comment: I've confirmed playback of the files that fail to load works properly in Windows Media Player as well as Audacity. I think I have a working fix having to do with the length reported after the RIFF tag (bytes indexed 4,5,6, and 7 in my byte array). I'll update with an answer if it does indeed work (I've only tested it on a single file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files that failed to load were each throwing an `InvalidOperationException` due to malformed files, but this was not because of any WAV format restrictions.

The error occurred in files where the length reported in bytes 4, 5, 6, and 7 of the files was different than the *actual length* of the data for the RIFF.

Windows Media Player and Audacity were compensating for this error, but the `SoundEffect.FromStream()` was detecting it and throwing exceptions.

Here is a working method I used to solve my problem:

```
private void _correctTheFileLength(string filename)
{
    byte[] wav = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

    string riff = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wav.SubArray(0, 4));
    if (riff != "RIFF" || wav.Length < 8) //check for RIFF tag and length
        return;

    int reportedLength = wav[4] + wav[5]*256 + wav[6]*65536 + wav[7]*16777216;
    int actualLength = wav.Length - 8;
    if (reportedLength != actualLength)
    {
        wav[4] = (byte) (actualLength & 0xFF);
        wav[5] = (byte) ((actualLength >> 8) & 0xFF);
        wav[6] = (byte) ((actualLength >> 16) & 0xFF);
        wav[7] = (byte) ((actualLength >> 24) & 0xFF);
        File.WriteAllBytes(filename, wav);
    }
}
```